# Mysql отрицательная релевантность при кросстабличном полнотекстовом поиске

Tags: mysql, join, match

Имеется вот такой вот запрос:

```
SELECT ban_id, ban_ip, user_email, user_id,
MATCH (ban_ip, user_email) AGAINST ('"46.39.228.87"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rev_0
FROM users RIGHT JOIN banlist ON ban_userid = user_id
WHERE MATCH (ban_ip, user_email) AGAINST ('"46.39.228.87"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY rev_0 DESC LIMIT 10
```

На выходе получается:

```
ban_id|ban_ip        |user_email|user_id|rev_0
91    |5555555       |NULL      |NULL   |-2
452   |412.35.348.42 |NULL      |NULL   |-2
90    |223.42.254.4  |NULL      |NULL   |-2
96    |24.175.253.143|NULL      |NULL   |-2
92    |88.112.234.132|NULL      |NULL   |-2
```

Т.е. в *AGAINST* может быть либо ip, либо email. Это нужно для того, чтобы в живом поиске выводились только релевантные результаты, а тут, получается, когда я использую `HAVING (rev_0) > 0`  и ищу по email - все нормально, когда ищу по ip - не выводится ничего.

Для `users` и `banlist` прописаны *fulltext* индексы. Почему у них отрицательная релевантность? из-за того, что `right join`? Пытался выполнить поиск по строкам, в которых поля `user_email`, `user_id` и т.д. не *null* - релевантность положительная.